# Injection EJB into Java Class

Tags: class, jakarta-ee, ejb, inject

How can i inject an EJB (3.0) in simple java class ?

When inject an EJB in my Java class, on execution i get a NullPointerException.

My Java Class test :

```
    public class test {
    @EJB MyEjb myEjb;

    public test(){
        myEjb.getUserbyId(2); // myEjb = null
    }
}
```

My EJB

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class MyEjb {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="jpa")
    EntityManager EM;

    public User getUserbyId(Integer id){
        ....
    }
```

Comment: How is your test executed? Your EJB is a class which is meant to be run on an application server, which is a container. The dependency injection only works there - but generally speaking, a test is executed by JUnit, but not within your container, where the EJB lives at runtime. So unfornutately, it's not so straight forward to run tests using EJBs! Try to learn about Arquillian and REST.... Arquillian is a way of running the container during the test, and if you implement a REST API in your EJB, you can then test that API via web requests.

Answer (score 0):

You should use InitialContext#lookup method to obtain EJB reference from an application server.
For example:

```
@Stateless(name="myEJB")
public class MyEJB {

  public void ejbMethod() {
    // business logic
  }

}

public class TestEJB {

  public static void main() {
    MyEJB ejbRef = (MyEJB) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/myEJB");

    ejbRef.ejbMethod();
  }


}
```